# Applying Delaunay Triangulation on RGB channels instead of final image

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, signal-processing, delaunay

First I applied Delaunay Triangulation on an image with 3000 triangles. I measured similarity (SSIM) to original image as 0.75. (The higher value more similar)

[image: Original][image: lena_transformed3000]

Then I applied Delaunay Triangulation on the image's RGB channels separately as 1000 triangles each. Then I combined 3 images and formed the final image. Then I measured similarity of this (SSIM) to original image as 0.65. (The higher value more similar)

[image: blue1000] [image: green1000] [image: red1000][image: Red_1000_Green_1000_Blue_1000]

In both cases; points chosen randomly, median value of pixels containing triangles choosen as color of the triangle

I did lots of trials but none of the trials showed better results.

Isn't this weird? Think about it. I just use 1000 random triangles on one layer. Then 1000 more on second layer. Then 1000 more on third layer. When these are put on top of it, it should create more than 3000 unique polygons compared to final image triangulation. Because  they do not coincide.

a) What can be the reason behind this?

b) What advantages can I obtain when I apply delaunay triangulation on RGB channels separately instead of applying it on image itself? It is obvious I can not get better similarity. But maybe Storage wise can I get better? Maybe in other areas? What can they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the triangles in each layer don't coincide, it creates a low-pass filtering effect in brightness, because the three triangles that contribute to a pixel's brightness are larger than the single triangle you get in the other case.

It's hard to suggest any 'advantages' to either approach, since we don't really know why you are doing this in the first place.

If you want better similarity, though, then you have to pick better points.  I would suggest making the probability of selecting a point proportional to the magnitude of the gradient at that point.